# Minesweeper Save Game Using Serialization

Tags: java, user-interface, serialization, deserialization

for my Computer Science class I have to create a minesweeper game that is able to be saved and loaded. I attempted this using serialization but it didn't end up working(I didn't get any errors, but nothing happens when I attempt to save or load and I am unable to find the saved file anyhere). He didn't say we had to use serialization, so I'd be glad to hear other ways to do this!

Thanks!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MineFrame extends JFrame implements java.io.Serializable
{
    MinePanel myPanel;
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    public MineFrame() 
    {
        setTitle("Minesweeper");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        myPanel = new MinePanel();
        getContentPane().add(myPanel);

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(file);

        JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save");
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/Minesweeper/minesweeper.ser");
                    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
                    out.writeObject(myPanel);
                    out.close();
                    fileOut.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException  e1) 
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        JMenu newGame = new JMenu("New Game");
        file.add(newGame);

        JMenu setDifficulty = new JMenu("Set Difficulty");
        mnNewGame.add(setDifficulty);

        //I left out the difficulty settings

        file.add(save);

        JMenuItem load = new JMenuItem("Load");
        load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                try
                {
                    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("/Minesweeper/minesweeper.ser");
                    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
                    myPanel = (MinePanel) in.readObject();
                    repaint();
                    in.close();
                    fileIn.close();
                }
                catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        file.add(load);

        JMenuItem quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        file.add(quit);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarcB I guess I didn't phrase that quite right, it worked in the sense that I didn't get any errors and didn't work in the sense that it didn't do what I wanted, nothing noticeable occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it is working its just the UI isn't updating, try this (in your load try catch):

```
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("/Minesweeper/minesweeper.ser");
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

//remove the old panel
getContentPane().remove(myPanel);

myPanel = (MinePanel) in.readObject();

//add the new panel
getContentPane().add(myPanel);

//revalidate
getContentPane().invalidate();
getContentPane().validate();
repaint();

in.close();
fileIn.close();
```

Comment: It is stil not updating, but thanks for the suggestion!